# Постоянно отображается страница приветствия Django

Tags: python, django

Следующая проблема: при любых условиях джанго выдает страницу приветствия (запуск с runserver). Сначала я думал проблема в том что я не правильно задаю **[url.py](http://url.py)**, но когда там ничего не нашел решил проверить все ли вообще в порядке: как оказалось нет. 
Для теста поделил на 0 прямо в **[setting.py](http://setting.py)** или отключал параметр **DEBUG** чтобы страница исчезла - не помогает. Пересутанавливал транк. Тоже.

В общем идеи кончились, не знаю что делать. Раньше на этой же машине все работало, и я нормально писал джанго-приложения, то случилось понятия не имею.

Comment: Чтобы исключить фактор пололанных библиотек — сделайте чистое окружение (`virtualenv --no-site-packages`), туда установите стабильную версию Django (`./bin/pip install Django`) и проверьте проект на работоспособность.

Answer (score 2):

[urls.py](http://urls.py):

```
# -*- coding:u8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', lambda x:render_to_response('index.html')),
)
```

в [settings.py](http://settings.py):

```
# путь до папки с шабломани
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/home/alexandr/domains/bigdata/templates',)
```

и в папку с шаблонами кладете файл index.html

```
<h1>hello world!</h1>
```

запускаете сервер и радуетесь))
если не радуетесь, то смотрите какие ошибки вам скажет Django..
стартовая страница Django отображается только в случае если не определен ни один url-паттерн в файле [urls.py](http://urls.py)

P.S: за lambda x:.. не пинайте) лень много кодить для копипасты
PPS: для приличия не плохо бы было показать [url.py](http://url.py) и [settings.py](http://settings.py) мы же не экстрасенсы